# Callable.call declared to throw Exception

Tags: java, exception

When I declare my `Callable.call()` method to throw `Exception`, the compiler (both Eclipse Neon and Oracle's javax 1.8.0_131 with `-Xlint:all`) remains silent, but when I declare it to throw `IOException`, the compiler sees that this can never happen.

```
public class CallableException implements java.util.concurrent.Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        // no warning -- why not?
        return null;
   }
}

public class CallableIoException implements java.util.concurrent.Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws java.io.IOException {
        // warning: declared exception IOException is not actually thrown
        return null;
   }
}
```

Why don't I get a warning for the `throws Exception` throw specification?

I understand that [Callable.call()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) is declared to throw Exception, but I can make my implementation throw less than the interface allows.

Comment: Not getting any warnings with my 1.8.0_112.

Comment: Because `Exception` includes `RuntimeException` and compiler assumes that any code can throw `RuntimeException` at any time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this happens because when you state that an `IOException` will be thrown, the compiler actually expects and checks for that specific type of Exception to occur in the method. This may be by calling a function known to throw it. Exceptions that the compiler checks for are known as *checked* exceptions. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) for more information.

If you just declare a regular `Exception`, the compiler doesn't bother because any piece of code could potentially produce an Exception. These are known as *unchecked* exceptions and are of `RuntimeException` decent.

In summary: When you specify a specific `Exception` (not `RuntimeException` or subclass of it) to be thrown. The compiler verifies it's possibility and gives a warning if it cannot happen. Which then means the throws clause is unnecessary.

Comment: Not an `Exception` of *any* kind. Only exceptions of the `RuntimeException` kind.